# PHP function returns NULL

Tags: php, function, return

I have the following function:

```
function MyReplaceListTag($myText,$number){ 

    if (strpos($myText,'<li>')===FALSE){

        $myResult= strip_tags($myText);
        return $myResult;

    }else{
        $number++;
        $pattern= '/<li>/';
        $replacement = "\n".$number."- ";
        $myText=preg_replace (  $pattern ,  $replacement ,  $myText , 1 );

        MyReplaceListTag($myText,$number);


    }
}
```

I call it with:

```
$result = MyReplaceListTag( $testTEXT,0);
```

Nothing is returned, var_dump($result) gives NULL.

I must be doing something incredibly stupid, but what?

Comment: If you pass a value in `$myText` that contains `<li>` then the function doesn't return anything (you don't have a return statement in the else block or at the bottom), which PHP treats as  NULL return

Comment: show the sample text

Answer (score 1):

Your function is returning `NULL` on the `else` block because it's lacking a return statement.

Change the `else` block from:

```
MyReplaceListTag($myText,$number);
```

to

```
return MyReplaceListTag($myText,$number);
```

---

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/Xj1IAP)

Comment: You're very welcome @mvdn. If my answer helped you, please mark it as the correct answer, thank you !